# Firebase automatic count based on another field

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a small app where i record votes and reorder a list based on those votes. The app has users and each user can only vote once.
For every record, when a user votes, i save the user id.

```
   var obj = {};
   obj[$scope.user.id] = {
       avatar: $scope.user.avatar,
       name  : $scope.user.name
   };
   myDataRef.child("sessions/"+sessionId+"/list/"+key+"/votes")
                            .update(obj, function(error){}
```

The update() protects me, and does not allow repeated ids.
With this i know that i have as many unique votes as voters.
So, i want a field called 'score' that would automatically count the users and set the 'score' field with that count.
How can i achieve this?

Tks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954217/is-the-way-the-firebase-database-quickstart-handles-counts-secure/37956590#37956590. But be aware that this is non-trivial in a real-time distributed client-only system.

Comment: doesn't seem like a duplicate. I don't have the answer to my question. its rather an alternative. I'm already doing that. I'm asking for a simple automatic count because it would fit my needs and would be much simpler.

Comment: It would indeed be a lot simpler if Firebase had built-in counting functionality. We're aware of the demand for it, but it doesn't exist at the moment. The question I linked is the current closest approach, unless you're willing to set up a server/run a trusted process.

Comment: Yes, it would :) I just followed your suggestion. Its working as intended. tks a lot.