# Firebase - Multi Path Update using Transactions in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, transactions, firebase-realtime-database

I've recently begun using the FirebaseDatabase library on Android Studio. So, I've read that when you update/modify multiple locations on your Firebase Database, in case any error occurs and to make sure that data isn't modified in some locations and not modified in other, **transactions** are used.

Transactions in JavaScript have been covered thoroughly and proper documentation has been provided. But, the documentation for the Android Studio library isn't very clear. The links are [link1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Transaction.Handler) and [link2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)
 


What is Mutable data and what value does it hold? Right now, this is how I update or modify the data on my database. I need to update values at nodes posts and user

```
HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put("/users/"+key+"/name/","New Name");
hm.put("/posts/"+key+"/number_of_posts/", 2);
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().updateChildren(hm, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        if(databaseError == null)
            Log.d(TAG, "TASK WAS SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED");
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "SOMETHING WENT WRONG");
    }
});
```

I know this is the wrong way to do this, so an explanation or a link to a tutorial to do this would be really helpful.

Comment: The Firebase documentation has a pretty decent example of transactions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions. But transactions and multi-path updates are inherently different, since [transactions only work on a single location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297884/how-can-i-use-a-transaction-while-performing-a-multi-location-update-in-firebase).

Comment: So is there any other secure way that I can carry out multi-path updates? Or is my current method the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So apparently this was the right way after all. Whenever you need to perform multi-path updates, you use a Hash-Map and the function updateChildren(hashMap). A completion listener is optional and can be added. 
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to combine multi-path updates with transactions with the introduction of `ServerValue.increment()`

```java
HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put("/users/"+key+"/name/","New Name");
hm.put("/posts/"+key+"/number_of_posts/", ServerValue.increment(2));
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().updateChildren(hm);
```

[Link to release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#realtime-database_v19-3-0)