# How can I combine updateChildren and runTransaction?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two references I want to update:

1.

```
/items/item1/sumlikes: 4
```

"item1" is liked by 4 users. I need a transaction because multiple users can write this value at the same time: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

2.

```
/users/myusername/item1: true
```

I add "item1" to the the username who liked it.

I would like to have the 1. and 2. writes atomic, so I need to use updateChildren with HashMap like in this example:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

But how can I combine this with a transaction? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to run a transaction across multiple disparate locations. The only way to have a transaction covering both locations, is to run the transaction at a common node above both locations. That will severely reduce the scalability/concurrency of your database.

Also see:

- [Firebase: How do I update multiple resources atomically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437695/firebase-how-do-i-update-multiple-resources-atomically)
- [How can I use a transaction while performing a multi-location update in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297884/how-can-i-use-a-transaction-while-performing-a-multi-location-update-in-firebase)

One thing I investigated at some point is using security rules and regular writes (including multi-location updates like yours) to achieve the same result. It's definitely possible. But it quickly gets quite tricky. See my answer on [Is the way the Firebase database quickstart handles counts secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954217/is-the-way-the-firebase-database-quickstart-handles-counts-secure)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I enjoyed reading your post about how to solve this with validation rules :) I hope I understand it well: if something goes wrong because several users update the same node at the same time the validation can fail and I will get an error or Android. What is the best practice to handle this fails? Should I retry the update a few times?

Comment: Yup. In that case you'd indeed have your code retry. It is quite similar to how Firebase's transactions also work: when the server detects a conflict, it rejects the new value and the client retries. The main difference is that with Firebase's built-in transactions it is the SDK code that does the retry, while in my linked answer it is my custom code.