# Firebase Referential Integrity in Realtime Database

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, referential-integrity

I am working on an iOS app where users can make posts and also favourite other users' posts. A user will be able to view all the posts s/he has favourited in a UITableView.

To achieve this, I am using Firebase as the backend, I have included my current database structure below.

```
root
  |
  ---posts
  |     |-post1
  |     |   |-title: "Post One Title"
  |     |   |-author: "userX"
  |     |-post2
  |     |   :
  |     :
  |     |-postN
  |
  ---users
  |     |-user1
  |         |-name: "John Doe"
  |         |-email: "example@gmail.com"
  |
  ---user-favorites
        |
        |-user1
            |-post1: true
            |-post2: true
```

In order to display all the favourite posts of a particular user (say *user1*), I currently observe the `/user-favourites/user1` reference for `childAdded` and `childRemoved` events. This works fine but here is the problem: suppose *post1* (which was made by *userX*) gets deleted, a reference to it is still in *user1*'s favourites, with time, *user1*'s favourites will have a lot of references pointing to non-existing posts.

How do I ensure that referential integrity is maintained, that is, if *post1* is deleted by *userX*, *post1* automatically goes away from the favourites list of *user1* (and also gets removed from the UITableview automatically), additionally, if *post1* gets modified (say its title is changed), the TableView of *user1* automatically reflects this new title too.

Rather than code samples, I am more interested in design recommendations, especially if you have experienced and solved a problem like this. However, suggestions are welcome, and if code samples show your point, then by all means post them. Thanks.

Comment: You'd use Firebase security rules to ensure the data stays in sync: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/. For a quite elaborate example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954217/is-the-way-the-firebase-database-quickstart-handles-counts-secure

Comment: Yes, Firebase rules are very simple individually, but when combined can be very powerful. You can use `updateChildValues` to post to multiple locations in one request and your rules can ensure the objects are created with their corresponding relations and vice versa.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I know about security rules and I can't see how they help in this situation.

Comment: @Callam, I also know about fanning-out data, but again, its not apparent how your suggestion tackles this particular problem. If the question was not clear, please indicate so and I'll edit it.