# Update my database when a data is written using Firebase rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I would like to update my database when a data is written.

Is it possible to do something like that in firebase's rules ?

```
"requests":{
      "$uid":{
        // On write, push id into /users/requestsId
        ".read":"auth != null",
        ".write":"root.child('users').child('requestsId').push($uid) && auth != null"
      }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Nope. Firebase Database rules cannot trigger side-effects, such as additional writes.

Comment: Sad... So how can I perform that?

Comment: By doing the multiple writes in code. If you have interdependencies between those two locations, you can secure them using rules. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954217/is-the-way-the-firebase-database-quickstart-handles-counts-secure/37956590

Comment: Thanks Frank !! :)