# how to prevent double upvote react- firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to prevent double voting in firebase.  My idea was to make a vote object in firebase and then add a user_id boolean every time someone votes. So `counterTips>votes>User_id1: true> UserId2: True.`

These were my security rules :

```
{

  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
      "CounterTips": {
     "votes": {
                "$uid": {
                    ".write": "auth.uid != null && auth.uid === $uid"
                }
              }
            }
  }


}
```

This is the way my db is structured

```
CounterTips 

 user_id: "rI9m9GEkyKhopAhaDNC8GNWPS943"

 vote: 5, 

 votes: 
1) bbz9MLo1u7T7zxugmHA806nMof93: true
```

I'm trying to push current users id into votes object,  but instead am just getting a static string that says  user_id: true. How do I push an actual user_id to votes and prevent that user from voting again in the security rules?

```
     upvotePost(key, vote, user_id) {

if (this.state.user_id !=null )
{

CounterTipsref.child("votes/${this.state.user_id}").once("value",snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.exists()){
      const userData = snapshot.val();
      console.log("exists!", userData);
    }


});
}

 else{
alert(this.state.user_id);
let user_id= this.state.user_id;
let votes = { [user_id]: true};

vote++;
CounterTipsRef.child(key).update({ 'vote': vote, 'votes': votes }); 
}
}
if (this.state.user_id==null) {

this.props.history.push('/login');
}


  }
}
```

Comment: my thought on this has always been: a boolean actually conveys 3 states (rather than 2), namely - `true`, `false`, and `null`. In other words, the property is the users `uid` and `true` for upvote, `false` for downvote, and non-existent (`null`) for no vote.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using this notation:

```
let votes = { user_id: true};
```

The `user_id` in here is seen as the name of the property, instead of the variable *holding* the name of the property. The quick fix is to use `[]` notation:

```
let votes = { };
votes[user_id] = true;
```

Comment: ok that works , so now how do i right security rule to prevent the user from voting twice?

Comment: The simplest way is to not keep a separate counter. If all you have is the collection of votes, and every user can only vote under their own UID, the votes are automatically unique. You can simply count the votes by downloading `votes` and counting them in the client. If you want to keep a separate counter, and ensure that updates to that are in line with folks adding/removing their UID, have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954217/is-the-way-the-firebase-database-quickstart-handles-counts-secure