# Firebase RTDB batched transactions (increment 2 values at the same time)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions, atomic

I am aware that you can do batched, atomic all or nothing updates using update - but can you do the same thing with a transaction?

Currently I am trying to increment a users friend count (2 users) at the same time when the friend request is accepted.

Here is what I am doing which works, but if something goes wrong it will lead to bad data inconsistencies which came about a couple times.

```
  const upOneFriend = firebase
    .database()
    .ref("users")
    .child(friend.uid)
    .child("friendCount");
  const upOneCurrentUser = firebase
    .database()
    .ref("users")
    .child(userUid)
    .child("friendCount");
  upOneFriend
    .transaction(currentCount => {
      return currentCount + 1;
    })
    .then(() => {
      upOneCurrentUser.transaction(currentCount2 => {
        return currentCount2 + 1;
      });
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("error increment");
    });
```

Like I said, is works, but I need to do this at the same time! I have looked around and have not found anything related to batch transactions for the Realtime Database.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions in Firebase Realtime Database work on a single node. If you need to update multiple nodes in a transaction, you'll need to run the transaction on the first common node above the ones you're looking to update. In your scenario that'd mean you run the transaction across `users`, which would probably significantly reduce throughput.

An alternative would be to use a multi-location update. But since a multi-location update doesn't auto-protect against concurrent writes, you'd have to include the information to protect against that in the write itself.

For an example of this, see my answer here: [Is the way the Firebase database quickstart handles counts secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954217/is-the-way-the-firebase-database-quickstart-handles-counts-secure/37956590#37956590), and [How to update multiple children under child node using a transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084222/how-to-update-multiple-children-under-child-node-using-a-transaction)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am not seeing this clearly, are there any examples you can lead me to or would you be able to provide me a little code snippet to see how this could be done?

Comment: Added a link to an example, although there's no clear cut copy/paste example. Honestly, unless you're quite experienced with Firebase already, I recommend sticking to the first paragraph.