# how to write batched transactions for firebase admin realtime db?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

is there a way to perform batched transactions on different fields in realtime database with admin sdk? Currently, I'm using the following:

```
exports.function = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    var transactions = new Object();

    transactions[0] = admin.database().ref('ref1/')
        .transaction(currentCount => {
            return (currentCount || 0) + 1;
        }, (error, committed, dataSnapshot) => {...})

    transactions[1] = admin.database().ref('ref2/')
        .transaction(currentCount => {
            return (currentCount || 0) + 1;
        }, (error, committed, dataSnapshot) => {...})

    return admin.database().ref().update(transactions)
                             //  |^|  error occurs right above '|^|', but i don't know why, i suspect it may have something to do with transactions object, and if so, what's the proper way to do batched transactions?
        .then(result => {...})
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('error: ' + error)
        })
}
```

but every time this function is called, although the transactions do work as a batch, the following error is thrown:

```
Unhandled error TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function
    at each (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:541:17)
    at validateFirebaseData (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1470:9)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1487:13
    at each (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:542:13)
    at validateFirebaseData (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1470:9)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1559:9
    at each (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:542:13)
    at validateFirebaseMergeDataArg (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1557:5)
    at Reference.update (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:13695:9)
    at admin.firestore.collection.doc.collection.doc.create.then.writeResult (/srv/index.js:447:43)
```

Comment: what is `transactions[0]` and `transactions[1]` - i.e. console.log them to see the content - by the way, should `transactions` be an Array instead of an Object?

Comment: @Jaromanda X, transactions[0] and transactions[1] just log [object Promise], and i was using an array before but when uploading function got warning to use object instead

Comment: so they are promises ... does `admin.database().ref().update` expect an object with promises?

Comment: @Jaromanda X nope, documentation doesn't say it accepts promises specifically, but it does accept objects with path to child as key and value and child as value, but i haven't been able to find anything on batched transactions, only batched writes. This is what documentation shows is valid: `usersRef.update({
  "alanisawesome/nickname": "Alan The Machine",
  "gracehop/nickname": "Amazing Grace"
});`, but that's just normal batched writes

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/f0jx2a/how_to_do_batch_transactions_in_functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a bunch of transactions into a `update()` call, which is what the error message is (admittedly somewhat confusingly) is trying to tell you.

Firebase has no concept of nested, or batched, transactions. If you need to perform a transaction over multiple locations, you will need to run this as a single `transaction` call over a node that is above all those locations. As you can probably guess, the contention on such a multi-location transaction is very quickly going to be a throughput limit, so you'll want to consider alternative solutions.

The "simplest" approach I can think of for your use-case, is to replace the two transactions with a single multi-location update, and then use server-side security rules to validate the operation.

For an example of how to do something similar, see my answer here: [Is the way the Firebase database quickstart handles counts secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954217/is-the-way-the-firebase-database-quickstart-handles-counts-secure)

With this approach you prevent most of the contention, as the multi-location update doesn't need to read-send-check the entire top-level node, but merely the lower-level nodes that you're updating.

You may have to modify you data structure, and possibly even write additional data, to allow this approach. But in return you'll get a much more scalable transactional update.

Comment: thanks, just ended up using `Promise.all( [transaction1 here] , [transaction2 here] )`, as I also need to do some other stuff in function (create firestore doc), and i think the most reliable way here would be with a callable function since i need to write to both databases