# Validating user data with Firebase records data in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an android voting application.
I have this code that inserts voters emails into a candidates key to help me count the total votes.

```js
public static void insertvote(String userkey, String categ, String candId, String uid) {
            DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            DatabaseReference totalVotesRef = rootRef.child("votes").child(categ).child(candId);
            Vote vote = new Vote(userkey);
            totalVotesRef.child(uid).setValue(vote.getVoterEmail());
```

It generates below results in firebase:

[image: Firebase database]

How can I enforce an email to only vote once and if it exists in the specific category, it disallows voting again? (For example in the image above, hr@gmail.com has been listed twice instead on only once meaning they can vote for a president twice) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I already showed you how to structure the data to allow only a single vote in my answer to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874553/firebase-rule-to-only-allow-one-update-in-android-studio/60879145#60879145. Any reason why you didn't adopt the data structure I showed there?

Comment: Ngugi k , @FrankvanPuffelen is an expert , you should have taken seriously whatever he suggested you , and you should  give preference his answer at that post over my answer at this post

Comment: Frank I did try to adopt the answer sir, but as I said I have not worked with Cloud Functions and therefore found myself more stuck. I did not want to bother you a lot out of courtesy.

Comment: Using the data model does not require using Cloud Functions, yet in this question you seem to not have made any of the changes to your data model that I proposed. Your current data model is just not great for the use-case you're trying to implement. If those changes were not clear, comment on my answer to your original question so that I can try to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I am **NOT A FIREBASE EXPERT** but i think that query will download all the data for all the votes.

**IF I AM NOT WRONG** querying all the votes which may be millions and then matching email and category might be an overkill.
I think you can create a flat structure for categories and put each category under it and when a voter votes put his id under that category.

```
like   cartegories :|
                |
                | president|
                |          |id:jrlkjew34234tlk 
                |          |id:rwjelk343243tjlke 
                |          |id:rjlwekr343ljlerer
                |          |
                | prime minister|
                |               |id:iorlue4324uoirew
                |               |id:eri34o3ljlewo234
```

Now when every time a votes put his id under the category he is trying to vote for and the query just that category and just match the id.

Something like that

```
public void vote(Voter voter){
    mDatabase.child("categories").child(voter.getCategory()) //getCategory() returns 
    //string that you will put under categories node, like pm , president etc
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                if(snapShot.getValue(String.class).equals(voter.getVoterId))
                   // if you get here he can't vote otherwise he can
          }   
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

That way you will be querying the particular category of votes , hence fast response and less download and less bill, and you can skip the category field from vote because you will be able to count vote by the new structure

**SOMEBODY PLEASE CORRECT ME IF I AM WRONG**

And OP can you please tell me what is the reason for saving the single category for a memeber if the member can vote for more than one category

Comment: Thanks id advance. Let me put this to test and give you feedback

Comment: you're welcome , and it may not be the best solution , you can wait for answers of experts in the field if you want, i answered what i thought is a good idea , surely it will work better than what you were doing , but better solution may exist .

Comment: Quick question, the "Voter voter" inside the parameters, what is it supposed to represent. Is it like an object?

Comment: a voter is an object in real life , it will have fields like age which should be over 18, gender in case you want to know the voting percent male vs female , an address in case you want to know which city has more voting percent , etc, you should create a voter popo it will be more object oriented

Comment: What should I pass as the parameter when I call the vote() function? Because Im calling it inside a recyclerview adapter in a onBindViewHolder() method.

Comment: i think you  have a design problem in the core of app , a voter may not vote everytime recyclerview is drawn on screen ,but if you calling it in the onBindViewHolder you still has access to the adapter data , you can pull a member from it. A suggest rethink your app.

Comment: in that case you should paste snapshots of your in app navigation

Comment: @NgugiKariuki i think first the users should get a list of elections which are going on , means the categories , like pm , president , then they should be provided with the names of candidates standing in that election, when user clicks the name , the details of candidate should appear with the promise that candidate make and his vision statement etc , so that the user can vote smartly , on the same page the vote button should be there,, in case you're very new start from building very simple apps, then climb your way up , you will learn a lot in the process

Comment: But thats the logic. Its only that I couldnt put all screenshots. This is the logic: login-> vote button ->Categories->candidates available (in the attached recyclerview image).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, under each voter profile, add a `boolean` field: .

If one has done voting, just mark it as True.

Use an `if else` to check for it by getting the value of `hasVoted` under the voter.

If the user is allowed to vote for different events, you can make the boolean using the event id, assuming you have developed a well-structured program, where everything has an id. For example, Brexit UK has an id of `123456789`, the field will be named as `hasVoted123456789`. Always query the `field` when user enters the page.

P/s: 
Frank presented a cleaner approach using in his [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874553/firebase-rule-to-only-allow-one-update-in-android-studio/60879145#60879145).

Comment: he wants user to vote more than once, like once for president , once for senator , or some other election , if a voter can vote only once the design would be much simple